# Internal Server Error readfile

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a view-script which opens a pdf-file, it looks like follows:

```
<?php
$this->title = 'arbeitskalender';
//ini_set('display_errors',1);
header('Content-Type:application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; fileName=arbeitskalender.pdf');
readfile('./pdfs/arbeitskalender.pdf');
?>
```

On my localhost (wamp-server) it works well and the file opens without any error, uploaded to my webspace (not my own server, only a webspace) I get

> internal server error

.

What's the problem? Is there a possibility to get a more informative error message? Because it is not my server, I can't have a look in the server log.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're in a class, but still using `$this`. Can you confirm whether this is actually inside a class or not?

Comment: Well, you need to look into the error log to see what actually caused the HTTP 500 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a lot of:

- check the network tab in your developer bar. Eventually, turn off (starts the header lines with //) your headers in your script to see the error message (for debugging)
- check the logfiles of your framework (if you use)
- check if your application can write log entries
- enable and display errors (see [Showing all errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings))
- check if php can read the file (permissions and existing of the file)
- check if you only get the internal server error on this page

Looking to your script:

- what's $this? I don't see a class definition
- can php find the file?

Answer (score 0):

Check `./pdfs/arbeitskalender.pdf` permissions. I guess it's not readable for `apache` user

Answer (score 0):

I checked all your suggestions, I learned some more, but couldn't solve the problem. I found another codesnippet which doesn't use `readfile` and so far this works fine.

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Pdf.php';

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=arbeitskalender.pdf');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');
echo file_get_contents("./pdfs/arbeitskalender.pdf");

?>
<html>
<body>
```